# TLS 1.2 Handshake failure due to peer reset at outlook.office365.com

Tags: ssl, office365, imap, handshake

I am trying to figure out why outlook.office365.com:993 is sending a RST to my client after the Client Hello of the TLS handshake. I have also validated that the box has the required DigiCert Global Root CA as part of the bundle.  Here is my test statement for connecting

```
openssl s_client -debug -msg -connect outlook.office365.com:993 


CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x1b85ef0 [0x1b85f70] (247 bytes => 247 (0xF7))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 f2 01 00 00-ee 03 03 5b 0f 23 30 2d   ...........[.#0-
0010 - 6a c0 8d ba a3 46 f8 76-0d e7 ff 5e 63 19 00 bc   j....F.v...^c...
0020 - 86 64 40 3e ed 29 fe 5c-28 bc d7 00 00 84 c0 30   .d@>.).\(......0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b   .,.(.$.........k
0040 - 00 6a 00 39 00 38 00 88-00 87 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .j.9.8.....2...*
0050 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
0060 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a2 00 9e 00 67   .+.'.#.........g
0070 - 00 40 00 33 00 32 00 9a-00 99 00 45 00 44 c0 31   .@.3.2.....E.D.1
0080 - c0 2d c0 29 c0 25 c0 0e-c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f   .-.).%.......<./
0090 - 00 96 00 41 c0 12 c0 08-00 16 00 13 c0 0d c0 03   ...A............
00a0 - 00 0a 00 07 c0 11 c0 07-c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00 04   ................
00b0 - 00 ff 01 00 00 41 00 0b-00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a   .....A..........
00c0 - 00 08 00 06 00 19 00 18-00 17 00 23 00 00 00 0d   ...........#....
00d0 - 00 20 00 1e 06 01 06 02-06 03 05 01 05 02 05 03   . ..............
00e0 - 04 01 04 02 04 03 03 01-03 02 03 03 02 01 02 02   ................
00f0 - 02 03 00 0f 00 01 01                              .......
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 00f2], ClientHello
    01 00 00 ee 03 03 5b 0f 23 30 2d 6a c0 8d ba a3
    46 f8 76 0d e7 ff 5e 63 19 00 bc 86 64 40 3e ed
    29 fe 5c 28 bc d7 00 00 84 c0 30 c0 2c c0 28 c0
    24 c0 14 c0 0a 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a 00 39 00
    38 00 88 00 87 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a c0 26 c0 0f c0
    05 00 9d 00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f c0 2b c0 27 c0
    23 c0 13 c0 09 00 a2 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 33 00
    32 00 9a 00 99 00 45 00 44 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29 c0
    25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41 c0
    12 c0 08 00 16 00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 07 c0
    11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00 04 00 ff 01 00 00
    41 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 08 00 06 00
    19 00 18 00 17 00 23 00 00 00 0d 00 20 00 1e 06
    01 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02 05 03 04 01 04 02 04
    03 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03 00 0f 00
    01 01
read from 0x1b85ef0 [0x1b8b4d0] (7 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 247 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

Here is a packet capture of the Handshake[image: TLS Handshake Screenshot]

I have compared this to another server that does work, and the Client Hello is identical with the exception of the 32bit UNIX Time and the random 28 bytes.

Can someone please help me understand why this is being reset by the peer, or at least what variables I need to consider?

Thanks in advance.

---Clarifying information---

The other server(Server B) was a different host in a different datacenter, it has the same openssl version OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013. I ran the same command on both and from server B and it pulled down the certificate chain. I also ran the same command from server A to smtp.gmail.com:993 and it grabbed a cert from that.

Comment: Does anything trigger a RST, like a non TLS handshake, just a pure telnet for example? If yes, it will show the problem is not TLS related but the endpoint just do not want to talk to you for whatever reasons (or some middleman cuts your connection).

Comment: I performed a telnet and typed in some erroneous ASCII data and no RST was triggered.  The pcap shows the psh,ack of the ascii data and it took it just fine.

Comment: If you say that the exact same traffic as beginning of a TLS handshake from another point works while yours do not work, I fail to understand how it can be happening without some filtering on the TCP/IP level. But when you say "to another server that does work" do you mean you tested your client with another host than `outlook.office365.com` or you tested another client (or same one) but from a different IP still towards `outlook.office365.com`? Of course you tested telnet on the same port (993) right?

Comment: FWIW `openssl s_client -debug -msg -connect outlook.office365.com:993` works from my IP. With a slight change in the dump, there is a "TLS 1.2 [length 0005]" before the "TLS 1.2 Handshake" that you had. But you forgot to specify which OpenSSL version you are using? And did you try with another one?  My local test was with version `1.0.2o`.

Comment: If that can help, see these testing results: https://tls.imirhil.fr/tls/outlook.office365.com:993

Comment: The other server(Server B) was a different host in a different datacenter, it has the same openssl version OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013.  I ran the same command on both and from server B and it pulled down the cipher.  I also ran the same command from server A to smtp.gmail.com:993 and it grabbed a cipher from that!!  And yes I was telnetting to 993.

Comment: Do I understand you right? You have two separate servers, both with the exact same version of OpenSSL, both connecting to `outlook.office365.com` and you observe that the connection works from one and not from the other? If that is so I really do not think it is a TLS problem. Anyway, please update your questions with all these additionnal data for others to contemplate before answering. And try a newer version of OpenSSL, 2013 is quite old...